# Generate String Permutaion

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am working on enhancing Search stored procedure for my website. I am currently using contains in it.

I want to generate string such that it contains the word multiple times i.e

If input is 'Gemini Sunflower oil' then string should be
 'Gemini Sunflower oil Sunflower Gemini oil Gemini Sunflower' so that i can use contains without any need of using AND and Or in Contains

Any Help...

Comment: Sounds like you need FTI http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: I have tried that way but using 'Or' or 'And' making my sp run slow thanx for ur support